# Bounding a sequence for the M test.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove or disprove that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(t) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^\frac{t}{n}$$ is a continuously differentiable function.

I'm trying first use the M test with $\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^\frac{t}{n}\}$ to show $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^\frac{t}{n}$ converges uniformly, but I'm having a hard time bounding each $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^\frac{t}{n}$.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: The $M$ test won't work because because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{t/n}$ don't converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is indeed continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R$. To see this, it suffices to prove that on every compact interval $I=[-M,M]$, the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{\frac{t}k}$$ converges (at least) at a single point $t_I\in I$ (EDIT: thanks to @MarkViola) and $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}e^{\frac{t}k}
$$uniformly converges. (Then, the series converges uniformly on every compact intervals $[-M,M]$ and the limit and the differentiation can be interchanged.)

> First claim : $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{\frac{t}k}$ converges at $0\in [-M,M]$ (for every $M>0$).

We have $$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{\frac{t}k}\Big|_{t=0}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}.
$$ And it is well-known that the alternating harmonic series converges to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}=-\ln 2.
$$

> Second claim : $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}e^{\frac{t}k}$ converges
>       uniformly on $[-M,M]$ for every $M>0$.

This is an immediate result of $M$-test:
$$
\sup_{|t|\le M}\left|\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}e^{\frac{t}k}\right|\le \frac{e^M}{k^2}.
$$

By the first and second claims, we know that $f(t) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{\frac{t}k}$ is continuously differentiable on $(-M,M)$ for every $M>0$. Thus $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is it clear that the alternating harmonic series is uniformly convergent?

Comment: @Diddysmash Yes, since it is a (convergent) series of constants. It certainly satisfies Cauchy's criterion: $\sup_{x\in \Bbb R} |\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^M \frac{(-1)^n}n| \xrightarrow{N,M\to\infty} 0$ since it does not depend on $x$. Is it convincing?

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Also, why do you use the $\sup$ here?

Comment: @Diddysmash Because we view $x\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ as (constant) functions of $x$, and apply Cauchy's criterion to these functions. But it is not really necessary.

Comment: You also used the sup for $\left|\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\left(e^{\frac{t}k}-1\right)\right|\le \frac{Me^M}{k^2}$. I've only seen the M test with absolute values with real valued functions.

Comment: @Diddysmash I'm not aware of your 'version' of Weierstrass $M$-test, but my statement is just equivalent to$$ \left|\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\left(e^{\frac{t}k}-1\right)\right| \le \frac{Me^M}{k^2},\quad \forall t\in [-M,M].$$ It is (probably) just another way of writing the same idea.

Comment: @Song It is not necessary to show that the original series converges uniformly.  It is sufficient to show that $(1)$ the original series converges at any single point on an interval $I$, $(2)$ the series obtained by differentiating under the summation converges uniformly on $I$.

Comment: @MarkViola Oops, you are absolutely right, sir. I've forgotten the full power of the theorem ... I appreciate for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{t}{n}}$ doesn't converge uniformly as a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$; there is no $N$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{t}{n}}$ is within the $1$ of the limit for all values of $t$, for example, because by making $t$ large I can make the next term of the series, $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}e^{\frac{t}{n+1}}$, as large as I like.

Even if the series did converge uniformly, that doesn't imly that the sum is differentiable.  The uniform limit of differentiable functions is not in general differentiable; you can see some counterexamples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability).

What you want to show is that the series converges and that the derivatives of the partial sums of the series converge uniformly.  The latter claim still isn't quite true: the convergence isn't uniform, but it is uniform on any bounded interval, and this is all you need: If you want to show that it is differentiable at a point, just show that it is differentiable on a bounded interval containing that point.

Comment: Could you nudge me a bit further by suggesting how to show the series converges. I know $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, do I use that?

Comment: (+1)  Nicely outlined.  You might want to be a bit more explicit when you write "the convergence isn't uniform, but it is uniform on any bounded interval," by writing "the convergence isn't uniform on $\mathbb{R}$, but it is uniform on any bounded interval